# Prove that a strictly increasing function with Intermediate value property is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition**: A real function $f$ has the *intermediate value property* on an interval $I$ containing $[a,b]$ if $f(a) < v < f(b)$ or $f(b) < v < f(a)$; that is, if $v$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is between $a$ and $b$ a $c ∈ [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = v$.

Prove that a strictly increasing function $f:[a,b] → R$ which has this property is continuous on $[a,b]$

Attempt:
Let $ε>0$ and $x∈[a,b]$. Consider $(f(x)−ε,f(x)+ε)$. By intermediate value property there is $x′∈f'(f(x)−ε,f(x))$ and $x″∈f'(f(x),f(x)+ε)$. Because $f'$ is increasing $x′<x<x″$. Now let $δ=\min(|x−x′|,|x−x″|)$.

Is this correct? How do I continue?

Comment: Try to clean your second lione{s last part ot make the statement clear, and also show what have you done so far.

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction, i.e. suppose $f$ is not continuous at some $z\in[a,b]$. (A strictly increasing function must jump up at any such discontinuity, so there will be a gap in the functions image and therefore the function will not have the intermediate value property.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue as follows.

If $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$, then $|y-x| < \min(|x-x'|, |x-x''|)$. Therefore,

- $|y-x| < |x-x'| = x-x'$, and
- $|y-x| < |x-x''| = x'' - x$

Rearrange the first inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}
|y-x| &< x-x' \\
\iff -(x-x') < y-x &< x-x' \\
\iff x' < y &< 2x - x' \\
\end{aligned}$$
(in particular, $x' < y$)

Rearrange the second inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}
|y-x| &< x''-x \\
\iff -(x'' - x) < y-x &< x'' - x \\
\iff 2x - x'' < y &< x'' \\
\end{aligned}$$
(in particular, $y < x''$)

The two inequalities combined therefore imply that $x' < y < x''$. As $f$ is increasing, this means that $f(x') < f(y) < f(x'')$. Recalling that
$$f(x') \in (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x))$$
and
$$f(x'') \in (f(x), f(x) + \epsilon)$$
we can conclude that
$$f(x) - \epsilon < f(x') < f(y) < f(x'') < f(x) + \epsilon$$
and therefore $f(y) \in (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon)$.

We conclude that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer has already been accepted but I made an attempt at the proof and wanted to get it verified.

Consider L such that f(a) < L < f(b). Take A= [f(a), L). Since f is increasing, sup[A]= L which implies there exists a sequence (Yn) converging to L. So, |Yn - L| < €, for n >= N. By the intermediate value property, there exists a sequence (Xn) in (a, b) corresponding to (Yn) such that |Xn - c| < d, for some d. This shows that f is continuous at c by epsilon-delta definition.